# Cannot find module 'install-npm-version'

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I'm developing this project with TypeScript: https://github.com/scott-lin/install-npm-version

When trying to consume the package within another project, I'm getting `Cannot find module 'install-npm-version'` error.

**Repro Steps**

1. `npm install install-npm-version@1.0.2`
2. Create repro.js file with `const inv = require('install-npm-version');` as the content
3. Invoke the repro with `node .\repro.js`

**Error**

```
> node .\repro.js
module.js:545
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'install-npm-version'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:470:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\scottlin.REDMOND\Desktop\test\repro.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
PS C:\Users\scottlin.REDMOND\Desktop\test>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main` property in the package.json file is used to find the module when using as an in-code Node module. Yours starts with a slash, implying the root directory. This is incorrect, which is why your code is failing.

**To fix:**

Change

`"main": "/lib/Install.js",`

to

`"main": "lib/Install.js",`

Comment: Wow, thank you. Not sure if I would have ever been able to debug this.